# Not able to find proto file from GIT submodule on remote branch

Tags: git, gradle, git-submodules, proto

I’m new to submodule and trying to add submodule that contains proto files to my gradle project.

```
project A
src/main/proto pointing to submodule project B
```

In my local, I’m able to compile this proto file after executing `git submodule update` because initially the folder that points to the submodule is empty.

But when I push my local branch to remote branch, the build fails because it doesn’t find the proto file.

```
> Task :generateProto NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileKotlin FAILED
```

I think this is because the submodule is not getting push to remote. I'm not sure how to make remote branch try to find the proto on the submodule B.

Comment: How the build is launched ?

Comment: You should add `git submodule update --init --recursive` as step of your build

Comment: The build is launched using build.gradle.kts.
How do I got about adding the submodule update to my build.gradle file ?